# Objective -C category issue

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-category

I have two `NSManagedObject` subclasses.
I am adding a category method to `NSManagedObject` for `JSON` representation, so I have this category named `NSManagedObject+JSON`.

Implement the category method in `NSManagedObject+JSON.m`:

```
- (NSDictionary *)JSONToCreateObjectOnServer {
@throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"JSONStringToCreateObjectOnServer Not Overridden" reason:@"Must override JSONStringToCreateObjectOnServer on NSManagedObject class" userInfo:nil];
return nil;
}
```

I am following Ray Weinderleich tutorial for this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2

It states:
The issue here is that there is no generic implementation possible for this method. ALL of the `NSManagedObject` subclasses must implement this method themselves by overriding it.

Whenever a `NSManagedObject` subclass does NOT implement this method an exception will be thrown.

**MY QUESTION HERE IS**:
I have added the method in category to my subclass. But my code does not call to the method in my `NSManagedObject` subclasses rather comes to category and throws an exception.

What is missing here?
Can anybody point out the reason behind it?

**EDIT 1:**

```
- (NSDictionary *)JSONToCreateObjectOnServer {
NSDictionary *date = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"Date", @"__type",
                      [[SDSyncEngine sharedEngine] dateStringForAPIUsingDate:self.date], @"iso" , nil];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                self.name, @"name",
                                self.details, @"details",
                                self.wikipediaLink, @"wikipediaLink",
                                date, @"date", nil];    
return jsonDictionary;
```

}

This is the method which I added to my NSManagedObject class.

I have copy and pasted it. Is it becoz of that or I have to follow another procedure to add method to NSManagedObject class.

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to help until you actually provide the code that is misbehaving.  You know, like maybe the actual implementation in the subclass, and the calls that are failing for starters.

Comment: Also provide the full code for the category, as the problem may lie in how the category was declared.

Comment: @MikeTaverne , please see my edit1 in my question

Comment: @JodyHagins , please see my edit1 in my question

Comment: That does not help much.  It's just a method that could be anywhere.  Please provide enough code to communicate the problem, but not more.  If you can't figure out what's going on with all of the code, others have little chance when presented breadcrumbs.  Objective-C works.  Properly implemented classes will result in derived class methods being called.  If that's not happening, then there is probably something wrong with the construction of the classes... or they are not being invoked properly.

Answer (score 2):

**Category is created for expanding, not for overriding or modifying**. So we cannot assure whether it override or be overridded.

In your case, instead of use Category, you should create a parent class which subclass NSManagedObject. Then put below method to parent class.

```
- (NSDictionary *)JSONToCreateObjectOnServer {
   @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:@"JSONStringToCreateObjectOnServer Not Overridden" reason:@"Must override JSONStringToCreateObjectOnServer on NSManagedObject class" userInfo:nil];
   return nil;
}
```

Another class will subclass your parent class instead of NSManagedObject.

P/S: Instead of throw, you should use NSAssert.

References:

- http://nshipster.com/nsassertionhandler/
- https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-05-03-proper-use-of-asserts.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/

Comment: Agree here. A category is a terrible place to put a must-be-implemented method that throws exceptions.

Comment: @Ares,  I agree that category is created for expanding , but if you look into the tutorial from ray weinderlich, there is a situation where you create category for JSON rep. of data and since generic implementation is not possible so same category method is implement in the category's base class .  Ray weinderlich says if we implement that method in category's base class , that method is called  from base class but not from category.    I just couldn't understand this and I have the problem where method is not called in my category's base class intead it's called in category .

Comment: @user3804063: yah, so I say we cannot assure which is called. You can figure out a lot of question, articles said about Overriding on Category or Overriding by Category. Not sure Raywenderlick absolutely right, and this tutorial is too old, since 2012.